# How to find this spin wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, spinors

If an electron is in a state that the probability of measuring spin along the +x axis is $P(+x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and the probability of measuring spin along the +y axis is $P(+y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, what is the wavefunction of the electron?

I tried to solve the above problem using a general spinor of the form $(a, b)^{T}$ but I' can't figure out the answer.

I used the equations:
$|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}=1,\quad P(+x)=|<\Psi_{+x}|\Psi>|^{2}=\dfrac{1}{2} \quad and \quad P(+y)=|<\Psi_{+y}|\Psi>|^{2}=\dfrac{1}{2} $, where $\Psi_{+x}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)^{T}, \quad \Psi_{+y}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,i)^{T} \quad and \quad \Psi=(a, b)^{T}$
but I couldn't find the values of a, b.

Here's exactly what I tried:

I wrote $\Psi$ as $\Psi=(cos\frac{\theta}{2}, sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi})^{T}$ so that the normalization is right. Then 
$$
|<\Psi_{+x}|\Psi>|^{2}=\dfrac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \\ \Big|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)(cos\frac{\theta}{2}, sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi})^{T}\Big|^{2}=\dfrac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \\
\Big( cos\frac{\theta}{2}+ sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}\Big)\Big( cos\frac{\theta}{2}+sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-i\phi}\Big)=1 \Rightarrow \\
$$

$$
cos^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}+sin^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}+cos\frac{\theta}{2}sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-i\phi}+cos\frac{\theta}{2}sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}=1 \Rightarrow $$
$$\\ cos\frac{\theta}{2}sin\frac{\theta}{2}cos\phi=0 \Rightarrow \\$$
$$\dfrac{sin\theta}{2}cos\phi=0 \Rightarrow \\$$
\begin{equation}
\boxed{sin\theta cos\phi=0}
\end{equation}
Following the same steps, this time starting from $|<\Psi_{+y}|\Psi>|^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ I also found that 
$$\boxed{sin\theta sin\phi=0}$$

So if $\theta=0$ then how can I find the value of $\phi$? Also, what about $\theta=\pi$?

Comment: You mentioned what you tried, but it would be helpful to explain why it didn't work for you. Is there some particular part of the work that's confusing?

Comment: I hope it is clear now

Comment: Two states are mutually exclusive. Hence +x state will have both $\pm y$ states hence if you choose one of them probability again reduce by $1/\sqrt2$. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases it is very helpful to write a and b in such a way that your first equation is automatically satisfied and the overall phase is neglected. I would take:
$$
\Psi = (\cos\theta,e^{i\phi}\sin\theta)^T
$$
You only have to find 2 free parameters now.

Concerning your edit. $\theta$ (your definition) is either 0 or $\pi$, which leaves the two possibilities
$$
\Psi_1 = (1,0)^T\\
\Psi_2 = (0,1)^T
$$

Comment: Can I somehow narrow it down any further into one spinor?

Comment: No because both wavefunction fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Not even as a linear combination of the two spinors?

Comment: No. A nontrivial (both coeffecients unequal zero) combination of the two does not fulfill the requirements. You don't have enough information to decide.